# Call and apply example can behave in code like this?

Tags: javascript, call, apply

I can understand why to use call and apply in the below example :

```
myObject = { name: "shafizzle",
 sayName: function() { console.log(this.name) } 
};
myObject.sayName ();

anotherObject = { name: "not me" }

myObject.sayName.call (anotherObject); // It will print "not me" as its called with anotherObject
```

**BUT**

If I want to print "not me" then I can directly create sayName in anotherObject and call it directly like this :

```
anotherObject = { name: "not me ",
 sayName: function() { console.log(this.name) } 
};
anotherObject .sayName ();
```

so I just wondering is there any concept to save memory by not writing the same function in multiple objects or any other advantage/purpose of using call for this?

Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

You have to simulate OOP in JS in order to achieve what you want.
Create a class using the prototype chain, then you just instantiate it.
i.e.:

```
function MyClass(name) {
   this._name = name;
   console.log("Hello, I am " + this._name);
}

MyClass.prototype._name; // Stores the name

MyClass.prototype.sayName = function() {
   console.log("I say: " + this._name);
}

var object1 = new MyClass("Johnny");
var object2 = new MyClass("Mary");

object1.sayName(); // Will output: I am Johnny
object2.sayName(); // Will output: I am Mary
```

Comment: Thanks you !! But rather than knowing different method of doing this , I am interested in knowing when we use call here, is there any specific advantage we will get of using call

Comment: call() allows you to override the "this" keyword. This points to the owner of the prototype chain in scope. Using call, the first argument you pass becomes the "this". The advantage relies in your code architecture, might be or might not be of advantage. Take a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call